# can't append data to NSMutableData getting segmentation fault 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, append, nsmutabledata

here´s the question, I'm receiving data from 2 textfields and I want to append that data into a mutableData to obtain just 1 array and send it through OutputStream. here´s the code

I declared as global variable the next

```
NSMutableData* bufferToSend;
```

at the init method I did the next:

```
bufferToSend = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
```

at the method where I send the info:

```
NSString* stringArrayFromTextField1;
[bufferToSend initWithCapacity:0];
stringArrayFromTextField1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[textfield1 text]];
[bufferToSend appendData:stringArrayFromTextField1]; //here gives me segmentation fault
```

When the code tries to executes the append it get crash am I missing something?

Comment: you can't append a NSString to NSMutableData. convert your NSString to NSData first.

Comment: And you should not call `initWithCapacity` again on the initialized object. And what is `getCurrentCmdBuffer`?

Comment: sorry getCurrentCmdBuffer is bufferToSend... so to append data it must be NSData type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors/issues in your code:

- `[bufferToSend initWithCapacity:0];` for the already initialized object makes no sense.
- The `[[NSString alloc] initWithString:...]` call is completely unnecessary, as 
  `[textfield1 text]` is already a string.
- `appendData:` expects `NSData`, not `NSString`. This is probably causing the crash.
  (Did the compiler not display a warning about incompatible types?)

The code then reduces to:

```
NSMutableData* bufferToSend;
bufferToSend = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

NSData *dataFromTextField = [[textfield1 text] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[bufferToSend appendData:dataFromTextField];
```

Comment: I see, Im new on this, no it didn´t show me an error or warning thanks for your help, now it´s working.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a *NSString* object where a *NSData* object is expected. However I don't see any reason to append it to the data that you have just created, since it's empty !! So this would be fine:

```
stringArrayFromTextField1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[textfield1 text]];
bufferToSend= [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: stringArrayFromTextField1] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I need to append data since I receive info from different textfields and they shall be in 1 array before sending. I tried your solution and It worked, thanks for your advice